# extract nested values as a list

Tags: sql, json, dictionary, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-substr

I have a table with a column "TAGS". Each row in this column has a bunch of dictionaries separated by commas. It looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "334",
    "name": "A",
    "synonyms": "tul",
    "path": [
        "179",
        "1689",
    ]
},
{
    "id": "8999",
    "name": "B",
    "synonyms": "hh",
    "path": [
        "1098",
        "167",
    ]
}
```

I want to create a new column "NAMES" that contains a list of all names. For example this:

```
NAMES
["A", "B"]
```

```
Select * from TAGS_TABLE
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apply regexp\_substr to each row separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853902/apply-regexp-substr-to-each-row-separately)

Answer (score 0):

Well your data is "almost" JSON, so if we convert it to json, we can then parse it, and flatten it:

```
with data as (
select parse_json('['||column1||']') as json from values
('{
    "id": "334",
    "name": "A",
    "synonyms": "tul",
    "path": [
        "179",
        "1689",
    ]
},
{
    "id": "8999",
    "name": "B",
    "synonyms": "hh",
    "path": [
        "1098",
        "167",
    ]
}'),
('{
    "id": "334",
    "name": "C",
    "synonyms": "tul",
    "path": [
        "179",
        "1689",
    ]
},
{
    "id": "8999",
    "name": "D",
    "synonyms": "hh",
    "path": [
        "1098",
        "167",
    ]
}')
)
select array_agg(f.value:name) within group (order by f.index) as output
from data d,
  lateral flatten(input=>d.json) f
group by f.seq
order by f.seq
```

gives:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| [ "A", "B" ] |
| [ "C", "D" ] |

### REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL

As already given to you in your other question...

```
select regexp_substr_all(column1, '"name"\\s*:\\s*"([^"]*)"',1,1,'e') as answer
from data;
```